# insert string at beginning of regex in python

Tags: python, regex

In below code, the string "Graph" is replacing the matched regex:

```
htmlText = re.sub("[0-9]*/index.html", 'Graph', htmlText, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

But the problem is, I want to prepend 'Graph' to the beginning of the matched `'[0-9]*/index.html'` expression, not replace it.

Comment: It should be: `htmlText = re.sub("([0-9]*/index.html)", 'Graph$1',htmlText,re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)`

Comment: Its not working, its replacing entire regex with Graph$1 as a string.

Comment: Backreferences are `\1` not `$1`, and need to be provided as a raw string. (Example in answer below.)

Comment: even after giving \1 , its replacing entire string with Graph\1

Comment: Right, you also need the raw string indicator (preceding `r`). You're managing to run into several gotchas all at once. :-) Answer below should get you through it, plus https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub is worth reading in full, for context / elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to capture the match (by surrounding your regex with parens), then backreference it (via `\1`), using a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) (via `r` before the replacement string) to prevent the backslash from being treated as an escape character:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: htmlText = "5/index.html"

In [3]: re.sub("([0-9]*/index.html)", r'Graph\g<1>', htmlText, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
Out[3]: 'Graph5/index.html'
```

Edit: Changed `r'Graph\1'` to `r'Graph\g<1>'` above, since that's more reliable in case someone uses this answer in a context where the backreference is followed by another number -- see docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub which cite:

> `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`

Note: Example above uses Python 2.7.6.

Comment: its not working , giving this error:   File "/apps/python2_6.6/lib/python2.6/sre_parse.py", line 795, in expand_template
    raise error, "invalid group reference"
error: invalid group reference

Comment: @GaganDeep Do you have the entire pattern `([0-9]*/index.html)` in parenthesis as shown?

Comment: Ahh, you need to replace the `r'Graph\1'` with `r'Graph\g<1>'` -- updating answer now.

Comment: Still getting the same error:error: invalid group reference

Comment: Could you add an "Update: Still seeing a problem with..." section to your question, including the ipython example that I gave in this question (repro-ing failure on your system), to see *exactly* how it differs on your system?

Comment: Thanks, perfect! You still aren't wrapping the regex in parenthesis. (I re-removed your updated example btw, to keep the original question clean.) You need `([0-9]*/index.html)` not `[0-9]*/index.html` -- the latter doesn't capture any groups, so the subsequent backreference to "group 1" is meaningless.

Comment: Fantastic. :-) Side note -- you could probably change `r'Graph\g<1>'` back to `r'Graph\1'` in your use case just fine, but you can also leave it as-is -- it's strictly less ambiguous this way.